# qt4 ошибка с qDebug

Tags: qt, c++

Почему выпадает ошибка в такой записи:

```
QList<QString> list;
list << "AAAA" << "BBBB" << "CCCC";

QListIterator<QString> it(list);

while(it.hasNext())
{
    QDebug() << "Element: " << it.next();
}
```

error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct QDebug’
forward declaration of ‘struct QDebug’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, вы не подключили [QDebug](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdebug.html).

```
#include <QDebug>
```

Comment: к тому же думается мне что нужно qDebug()